# Securely submitting passwords via REST API

Tags: rest, powershell, security

I'm new to working with RESTFUL Api's. I'm trying to Write a PS Module for interacting with the CommVault API (http://documentation.commvault.com/commvault/v11/article?p=features/rest_api/test_environment_sandbox.htm)

The documentation seems good and I don't think I'll have much of a problem but I'm concerned about the way it authenticates. It's using the POST method instead of GET, but still submitting the password as Base64 encoded, rather than any real encryption. How secure is this **really**? Could someone check network traffic and determine my password?

I'm starting with something like this:

```
$userName = Join-Path $env:USERDOMAIN $env:USERNAME
$credential = Get-Credential -UserName $userName -Message "Enter password for user $userName." 
$SERVER = "myserver.com"  
$APIURL = "http://$($SERVER):81/SearchSvc/CVWebService.svc"  

$APIURLaction = "$APIURL/login"  
$passwordB64byte = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password)  
$encodedPassword = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($passwordB64byte)  
$loginReq = "<DM2ContentIndexing_CheckCredentialReq mode=""Webconsole"" username=""$userName"" password=""$encodedPassword"" />"  
$result = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $APIURLaction -Method POST -Body $loginReq -UseBasicParsing        
$token = (([xml]$result.content).SelectSingleNode("/DM2ContentIndexing_CheckCredentialResp/@token")).value
```

Credit to: http://setspn.blogspot.co.uk/2015/04/commvault-rest-api-using-powershell.html

Comment: If you are using http, you are correct that it's not secure. You need to use https instead.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, in fact I just found the following on Stack. If I'd just searched for a few moments more before posting :)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48409943/securely-submitting-passwords-via-rest-api

Comment: Turns out the Base64 is not for security, but just to avoid screwing up any messages with certain special chars. I'll look into https. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @bill_stewart , you should be using HTTPS anytime your app is posting sensitive data over the wire.